# Uploading blob type images to database, my code says it is uploading the image but not being stored in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, file-upload

This is my code below, the HTML form at the top is a simple form to upload an image and the SQL commands within the PHP is for uploading to the database. The problem I am having is it appears to be accessing the if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image") and outputting "Image uploaded" to the browser but not actually uploading this image to my database.

My database table named blob has three fields; id (int(11) also auto increment and primary key), name (varchar(30)) and image (blob).

Edit: I tried the backticks suggested by M Miller but no luck, using the    mysql_error() gave me this error
    Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Box\index.php on line 31

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Image Upload</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="index.php" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");//password root
    mysql_select_db("content");//db name content

    $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);//provides protection against injection
    $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));

    $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);

    if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image")
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'blob' VALUES('','$imageName','$imageData')");
        echo "Image Uploaded";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Only images are allowed";
    }

}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Similar to BarryDevSF's solution by changing the line to read:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `blob` VALUES(NULL,'$imageName','$imageData')");
```

instead of:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'blob' VALUES('','$imageName','$imageData')");
```

solved the issue.

Comment: When in doubt with a MySQL query, try `mysql_error()`. Also, you should use `mysqli_*` functions or the PDO extension, as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will eventually be removed from PHP. My guess is that you should use backticks (\`) around `blob` instead of single quotes (').

Comment: Storing image data in the DB is a pretty bad idea well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an empty string to the INT id.  I would try it without that.

instead of:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'blob' VALUES('','$imageName','$imageData')");
```

try:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO blob (name, image) VALUES('$imageName','$imageData')");
```